# Vue Laravel Pusher. How to leave a channel

Tags: vue.js, pusher

OK this has been posted a few times and while each of the solutions seem similar, none of them work for me. So lets start with the code.

Main.vue

```
<template>
...
<room-tabs :selectedRoomId="currentRoom.id" :rooms="joinedRooms"
                                   @onSelectRoom="currentRoom = $event" @onLeaveRoom="leaveRoom($event)"/>
...
</template>

methods: {
        connect() {
            if (this.currentRoom?.id) {
                let vm = this;
                this.getMessages();
                Echo.join("chat." + this.currentRoom.id)
                    .here(users => {
                        this.sendUserActivityNotification(this.$page.props.user, true)
                        this.users = users
                        this.usersCount = users.length
                    })
                    .joining(user => {
                        this.users.push(user)
                        this.usersCount = this.usersCount+1
                    })
                    .leaving(user => { 
                        this.sendUserActivityNotification(user, false)
                        this.users = this.users.filter(({id}) => (id !== user.id))
                        this.usersCount = this.usersCount-1
                    })
                    .listen('NewChatMessage', (e) => {
                        vm.getMessages();
                    });
            }
        },
        leaveRoom({id}) {
            Echo.leave("chat." + this.currentRoom.id)
            this.$store.splice(RoomTypes.LEAVE_ROOM, id)   
        }
    },
```

RoomTabs.vue

```
<template>
...
<XIcon class="float-right h-3.5 w-3.5 -mt-2 -mr-2 text-black" aria-hidden="true" @click="leaveRoom(selectedRoomId)"/>
...
</template>

<script>
import {XIcon} from '@heroicons/vue/solid'
import {types as RoomTypes} from "../../../Store/modules/rooms/rooms.types";


export default {
    components: {
        XIcon,
    },
    props: ['rooms', 'selectedRoomId'],
    emits: ['onSelectRoom', 'onLeaveRoom', 'onClose'],
    methods: {
        leaveRoom(id) {
            this.$store.splice(RoomTypes.LEAVE_ROOM, id) 
            this.$emit('onClose');
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

I cannot seem to disconnect from the room when I click the X on the room tab. What am I missing here?

Comment: Seems that [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) is not the right function here `this.$store.splice(RoomTypes.LEAVE_ROOM, id)`.

Comment: @iPaat so what do I use to remove an item from the array?

Comment: From the information given, I can't tell. But you have to find the right keys which you could pass to splice. It expects an start index and a count how many items should be deleted. I don't think it makes sense to have a roomId there.